# Binary operators and overloading, addition and so forth

Tags: c++

I can't add together more then 2 things in each object. for example. I have a xCord, a yCord, a radius, a circumference, and a area. When I add the objects together only the xCords and yCords add together. The rest stay at what they were set to.

The circleT.h file, also my compiler is older so it can't handle having templates in the cpp for some reason. So everything is in the header file if you are wondering.

```
//  MATHEMATICAL OPERATORS

// BINARY operators
template<typename T> 
CircleT<T>  CircleT<T>::operator+(const CircleT<T>& rhs)
{
    CircleT temp;
    CircleT tempC;
    temp.xCord =  this->xCord + rhs.xCord;
    temp.yCord =  this->yCord + rhs.yCord;
    temp.radius = this->radius + rhs.radius;
    return temp;
}

template<typename T> 
CircleT<T>   CircleT<T>::operator-(const CircleT<T>& rhs)
{
    CircleT temp;
    temp.xCord =  this->xCord - rhs.xCord;
    temp.yCord =  this->yCord - rhs.yCord;
    return temp;
}
template<typename T> 
CircleT<T>   CircleT<T>::operator*(const CircleT<T>& rhs)
{
    CircleT temp;
    temp.xCord =  this->xCord * rhs.xCord;
    temp.yCord =  this->yCord * rhs.yCord;
    return temp;
}
template<typename T> 
CircleT<T>   CircleT<T>::operator/(const CircleT<T>& rhs)
{
    CircleT temp;
    temp.xCord =  this->xCord / rhs.xCord;
    temp.yCord =  this->yCord / rhs.yCord;
    return temp;
}


//  UNARY operators
template<typename T> 
CircleT<T>&   CircleT<T>::operator+=(const CircleT<T>& rhs)
{
    this->xCord += rhs.xCord;
    this->yCord += rhs.yCord;
    return *this;
}
template<typename T> 
CircleT<T>&   CircleT<T>::operator-=(const CircleT<T>& rhs)
{
    this->xCord -= rhs.xCord;
    this->yCord -= rhs.yCord;
    return *this;
}
template<typename T> 
CircleT<T>&  CircleT<T>::operator*=(const CircleT<T>& rhs)
{
    this->xCord *= rhs.xCord;
    this->yCord *= rhs.yCord;
    return *this;
}
template<typename T> 
 CircleT<T>&  CircleT<T>::operator/=(const CircleT<T>& rhs)
{
    this->xCord /= rhs.xCord;
    this->yCord /= rhs.yCord;
    return *this;
}

 template<typename T> 
CircleT<T>&   CircleT<T>::operator=(const CircleT<T>& rhs)
{
    this->xCord = rhs.xCord;
    this->yCord = rhs.yCord;
    return *this;
}

template<typename T>
CircleT<T>  CircleT<T>::operator++(int ignoreThis)
{
    //  this is the   **  POST ** increment
    double tempxCord = xCord;
    double tempyCord = yCord;
    xCord++;
    yCord++;
    return CircleT();
}
 template<typename T> 
CircleT<T>   CircleT<T>::operator++()
{
    //  this is the   **  PRE ** increment
    xCord++;
    yCord++;
    return CircleT();
}



 template<typename T> 
CircleT<T>   CircleT<T>::operator--(int ignoreThis)
{
    //  this is the   **  POST ** increment
    double tempxCord = xCord;
    double tempyCord = yCord;
    xCord--;
    yCord--;
    return CircleT();
}
template<typename T> 
CircleT<T>   CircleT<T>::operator--()
{
    //  this is the   **  PRE ** increment
    xCord--;
    yCord--;
    return CircleT();
}




    // LOGICAL operators
template<typename T>
bool  CircleT<T>::operator==(const CircleT<T>& rhs)
{
    return  (  this->xCord == rhs.xCord  &&  this->yCord == rhs.yCord   );
}
template<typename T>
bool  CircleT<T>::operator!=(const CircleT<T>& rhs)
{
    return  (  this->xCord != rhs.xCord  &&  this->yCord != rhs.yCord   );
}
template<typename T>
bool  CircleT<T>::operator<(const CircleT<T>& rhs)
{
    double areaL = this->xCord * this->yCord;
    double areaR = rhs.xCord * rhs.yCord;
    return  (   areaL < areaR    );
}
template<typename T>
bool  CircleT<T>::operator<=(const CircleT<T>& rhs)
{
    double areaL = this->xCord * this->yCord;
    double areaR = rhs.xCord * rhs.yCord;
    return  (   areaL <= areaR    );
}
template<typename T>
bool  CircleT<T>::operator>(const CircleT<T>& rhs)
{
    double areaL = this->xCord * this->yCord;
    double areaR = rhs.xCord * rhs.yCord;
    return  (   areaL > areaR    );
}
template<typename T>
bool  CircleT<T>::operator>=(const CircleT<T>& rhs)
{
    double areaL = this->xCord * this->yCord;
    double areaR = rhs.xCord * rhs.yCord;
    return  (   areaL >= areaR    );
}
```

Comment: Please narrow your wall of code to the relevant stuff!!

Comment: narrowed it down to the operation functions

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator =` function only copies the x and y coordinates, not the radius. So even when the + operator works, the assignment does not.

Comment: Also, there is a line to add the radii in `operator+`, but there is nothing equivalent in `operator-`.

Comment: I know, but since the + isn't working why would I move on lol

Comment: Was that for me or for @RSahu? Your + is working, but when you assign the result of the + to something using =, you lose the radius value.

Comment: @TheDark yes, it was meant for you. As the OP already commented, that is a known issue and we can ignore it for now.

Comment: @RSahu I mean the OP's comment. The `operator =` problem is what is causing the issue, so it can't be ignored.

Comment: @TheDark Agree with you. The problem in `operator=` can't be ignored. I was saying we can ignore the problem in `operator-` since the OP is aware of it.